# Observer not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

I am trying to pass additional options from quote item to order item using following observer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">

        <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after_addtionaloptions" instance="<<CompanyName>>\Catalog\Observer\AdditionalOptions" />

    </event>

    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">

        <observer name="copy_quote_additionaloptions_to_sales" instance="<<CompanyName>>\Catalog\Observer\CopyQuoteAdditionalOptionsToSales" />

    </event>

</config>
```

And following is the observer php code

```
<?php
namespace <<CompanyName>>\Catalog\Observer;

//use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CopyQuoteAdditionalOptionsToSales implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $quoteItems = [];
    private $quote = null;
    private $order = null;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger){
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->debug("Inside sales execute method");
        $this->quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $this->order = $observer->getOrder();
        /* @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem */
        foreach($this->order->getItems() as $orderItem){
            if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
                if($quoteItem = $this->getQuoteItemById($orderItem->getQuoteItemId())){
                    if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                        //To do
                        // - check to make sure element are not added twice
                        // - $additionalOptionsQuote - may not be an array
                        if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')){
                            $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                        }
                        else{
                            $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                        }
                        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
                            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                            $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function getQuoteItemById($id){
        if(empty($this->quoteItems)){
            /* @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
            foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item){
                //filter out config/bundle etc product
                if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
                    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->quoteItems)){
            return $this->quoteItems[$id];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

quote_item_option table has the data. 
Now whenever I place an order, the above observer **execute** function doesn't
execute.

Comment: please sepcify the locations this file in your question. Also your event declaration code looks incomplete.

Comment: PHP observer file is in `<<companyname>>\Catalog\Observer\CopyQuoteAdditionalOptionsToSales.php`
and event file is in `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\frontend\events.xml`.
I have edited the events.xml file

Comment: can you move your event file to `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\events.xml` and try ? make sure you cleared all your cache and do a `setup:upgrade` after that

Comment: I put an answer. Please go through it and accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better you move your `events.xml` location from `frontend` to `global` scope. In order to do this, you just want to move your `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\frontend\events.xml` file to `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\events.xml`.

After do this changes, clear all your cache, then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. You will see your events will get fired.

#### So what happend when we add event declaration under `frontend` section ?

M2 checkout is highly uses rest api calls internally. This is achieved by using knockout js. Expalining this is out of scope for this particular question. However, the key point is, when Magento uses rest api calls to do something, it's scope would become `rest_api`. This means, your observer will be observed only if you add your event in `rest_api` scope too.

So the optimum solution here is move your `events.xml` file to `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\frontend\events.xml` and `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\rest_api\events.xml` locations.

You can also achieve the same behaviour by simply moving your `events.xml`  file to `<<companyname>>\Catalog\etc\events.xml`. Now irrespective of the area, your event will get fired.

Hope that clarifies your doubts.