# Observer doesn't catch event Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.3, magento2.1.5

I have implemented 2 observers for **checkout_cart_product_add_after**, **sales_order_place_after** event. But these observers didn't catch events.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="websoftpro_utm_after_checkout_event" instance="WebSoftPro\UTM\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="websoftpro_utm_after_add_to_cart_event" instance="WebSoftPro\UTM\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer file**

```
namespace WebSoftPro\UTM\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $quoteItem =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    }
}
```

I have used xdebug to debug. It went through this code:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
            ['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]
        );
```

But it doesn't go to the Observer file.

What is the problem ?

Somebody, please help me out.
Please!

Comment: Your function argument should be  `public function execute(Observer $observer)` because you already added `use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;`

Comment: Yeah, But it is not fixing the problem

Comment: Where have you placed your events.xml file? under etc folder or etct/frontend?

Comment: i tried both of these place above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution in this post:
[Observer not working in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159432/observer-not-working-in-magento-2?rq=1)

For that to work:

1. **`Move the file events.xml to global (ModuleName/etc folder)`**
2. **`Clear all cache`**
3. **`run: php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated`**

Comment: I want to call every time this event **controller_front_send_response_before**. This idea does not work for me.

Comment: If that help, please vote up.

Comment: Thanks - had similar issue, and moving events.xml from frontend to "global" did the trick for me.